# Запись пути в cookies

Tags: php, cookie

Добрый день, друзья!

Есть код:

```
$sid = ("Голос принят");
$y2k = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2200);
$pathe = ("/index.php?org_id=cat");
setcookie("id_shop", $sid, $y2k, $pathe);
$_COOKIE["id_shop"] = $sid;
```

Так вот почему-то, проверяя кукисы в браузере, путь не записывается!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прописал путь без $pathe, сразу прямой:

```
setcookie("id_shop", $sid, $y2k, "/index.php?org_id=cat");
```

и заработало!